# Which comes first?, the distribution $P_X$ or the measure $\text{Prob}$?

Tags: probability-theory

I'm currently re-learning probability through measure theory, and I came across these definitions:

- A probability space is a measurable space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ with a $\sigma$-additive measure $\text{Prob}\colon\mathcal{F}\to[0,+\infty)$ that obeys $\text{Prob}(\Omega) = 1$.
- The distribution of a random variable $X\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is the measure in $\mathbb{R}$ given by $P_X(A) = \text{Prob}(X\in A)$.

However, in practice, most probability calculations arise in the context of random variables. If we have e.g. $X \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$, then we usually do computations like $\text{Prob}(X = k)$ by using the distribution of $X$ (and the fact that it has a density).

$$\text{Prob}(X=k) = p_X(k) = e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$$

My question is: what is $\text{Prob}$ here? (knowing that the sample space is $\Omega = \mathbb{N}_0$), **it feels as if we are using the distributions of random variables to define $\text{Prob}$ instead of computing it.** We almost never specify the sample space when we say things like $X\sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$, or any distribution for that matter. Is there a standard for choosing e.g. the counting measure in finite spaces and some other measure for the continuous case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In practice the underlying probability space is abstract, and has the features that we need to define the random variables that we would like to define. It is a separate mathematical task, which most users of probability theory do not concern themselves with, to show that a suitable probability space for a given situation actually exists. For example, it's not immediately obvious how to construct a probability space on which a sequence of independent continuously distributed variables can be defined, but it can be done, and in practice most people take this fact for granted.

Only very occasionally do we need to grapple with the possibility that no such space exists (for example, this derails any attempt to classically define white noise).